# NLog in .NET 4.5 console app: not loading Configuration

Tags: c#, console-application, nlog

I have some console apps I've written at work. I'd like to get NLog into them but I am having trouble.
When I inspect the 'logger' object, I see in it's 'Factory' property, that the configuration had targets=0, loggingrules=0, everything blank or unset.
So, it doesn't do ANYTHING.. doesn't drop an internal log file either... I have tried nLog.config NLog.config and nlog.config... to no avail. Tried ver 3 and 4 of NLog too...

Why would it not pick up the config?

I have:

- NLog.config in the root with 'Content' for build action and 'Copy Always' set
- Confirmed the NLog.config IS being copied to the bin
  [image: screenshot1]

Here's the NLog.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\NlogInternal.log"
      internalLogToConsole="true"
      internalLogToConsoleError="true"
      internalLogToTrace="true">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="debugConsole" layout="${message} "/>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="debugFile" createDirs="true" fileName="c:\temp\testlog.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugConsole"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugFile"/>    
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

and finally (this doesn't error, but nothing is output since the config is blank):

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Info("ConsoleApp test log...");
```

Comment: I don't have a solution but your config file looks great. I replaced the contents of one of my config files (named "Nlog.config") and it works exactly as you'd expect, dumping huge amounts of info to the console and writing the info log .log file as directed. I also use the exact same logger.Info method in that project, and I have the same build actions set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your app.config have a NLog configSection?
Something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No, because I am using the external NLog.config file. When you use an external you don't need to touch the app.config as per https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations

Comment: @Beau, do the nloger.config IS on the root of the application or in bin of the application? (like this: project/bin/bin)

Comment: In my explanation: "Root of app with 'Copy Always' set" (so it copies to the bin, also)

Comment: There was still a blank NLog node in my main web.config... (the web.config has a lot in it) It wasn't finding/loading the NLog.config file because it had already found an NLog node in the web.config... My bad.

Comment: Worth stressing that the `<configuration>` element should be placed as the first one in the `app.config`.

Answer (score 1):

If even the internalLogger isn't working, you could debug the issue by setting
the [`InternalLogger.LogWriter`](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/P_NLog_Common_InternalLogger_LogWriter.htm)

e.g.

```
 // enable internal logging to a custom TextWriter
    InternalLogger.LogWriter = new StringWriter(); //e.g. TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("C:\\perl.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue on my end. When you make change your fileName Path "c:\temp\testlog.log" to 
"c:/temp/testlog.log" then it will work. Hope the below snipet help you to resolve the issue.

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="Console" name="debugConsole" layout="${message} "/>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="debugFile" createDirs="true" 
      fileName="c:/temp/testlog.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} 
      ${message}"/>
 </targets>
 <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugConsole"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugFile"/>
 </rules>
```